# Raspberry Pi Compiling multiple C++ Files with SQLite3 and SDL2

Tags: c++, sqlite, g++, sdl-2, raspberry-pi3

How would you compile multiple c++ files that are using SDL2 and sqlite3 on a Raspberry Pi 3? If the setup was 6 cpp files being compiled using g++ on a Raspberry Pi 3, and each of those files used the SDL2 library, and 2 used the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files, what would the command look like for g++?

I have installed SDL2, SDL2_image, and SDL2_ttf on my Rasberry Pi 3 and I have the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files inside of the file with all of the cpp files. I've tried this command:

```
g++ -std=c++0x Source.cpp Basic_Image.cpp Clock.cpp Text.cpp Widget.cpp TextDatabase.cpp -o Source `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -LSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
```

and received this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file -I/usr/local/include/SDL2: No such file or directory Collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

SDL2 is installed on my Raspberry Pi 3, so why it would throw no such file or directory confuses me.

Comment: I just realized this, however after fixing it i get a bunch of undefined references to sqlite3 commands such as 'sqlite_open', etc.. @genpfault

Comment: Well, yeah, you aren't linking against sqlite.

Comment: What does that mean? Should I be trying to link sqlite3 just like I am with SDL2?

Comment: Yup, though I'd recommend using [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) for both SDL2 (instead of `sdl2-config`) and SQLite.

Comment: So what would the exact command look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to compile with prelinked libraries you must run the following command into a terminal:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x Source.cpp Basic_Image.cpp CLock.cpp Text.cpp Widget.cpp TextDatabase.cpp -o Source $(pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_image SDL2_ttf sqlite3)
```